# Pass PHP through redirect and custom fields

Tags: custom-field, rewrite-rules, post-type

I'm trying to construct an easy to use affiliate site, each post-type has a custom field where keywords can be entered per post.  ( using advanced custom fields plugin )

Then in a template I call that field into a URL like this :

```
<?php if( get_field('amazon_keywords') ): ?>
            <a href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&field-keywords=<?php the_field('amazon_keywords'); ?>&linkCode=ur2&tag=AFFID"> More info Test dynamic Amazon</a>
    <?php else : ?>
            Something else
    <?php endif; ?>
```

This works and displays the link with the entered keywords.

**PROBLEM**

Because its an affiliate link, best practice would be to mask it.  So instead of showing the affiliate link id like to show it something like :

```
website.com/goto/amazon
```

Normally this is fine because I can just do a redirect,  but the addition of the php inside the URL for the keywords is where I've stumbled.

Anyone have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without touching [rewrites](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) - you could probably do somthing like

```
website.com/?goto-amazon=<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>
```

Which'ed output

```
website.com/?goto-amazon=42
```

Where `42` is an example of a post that contains the `amazon_keywords`.

In your site you could listen for the `goto-amazon` query and redirect thereafter

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    if (isset($_GET['goto-amazon'])) {
        $keywds = get_field('amazon_keywords',intval($_GET['goto-amazon']));
        $link = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&field-keywords={$keywds}&linkCode=ur2&tag=AFFID";
        wp_redirect($link);
        exit;
    }
});
```

---

### UPDATE

To do with rewrites you could so something like so. On your post

```
$url = get_site_url();
$id = get_the_ID();
echo "<a href='{$url}/goto/amazon/{$id}/'>go to Amazon</a>";
```

Which'd make a link like

```
website.com/goto/amazon/42/
```

Then in your functions

```
add_action( 'init', function(){

    // uncomment reload once or twice, or hit SAVE in wp-admin > Settings > Permalinks
    //flush_rewrite_rules();

    add_rewrite_tag('%gotoamazon%','([^&]+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^goto/amazon/(.*)/?','index.php?gotoamazon=$matches[1]','top');
});


add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    global $wp_query;
    if ($goto = get_query_var( 'gotoamazon' )) {
        $keywds = urlencode(get_field('amazon_keywords',intval($goto)));
        $link = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/?_encoding=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=19450&field-keywords={$keywds}&linkCode=ur2&tag=AFFID";
        wp_redirect($link);
        exit;
    }
});
```

When dealing with rewrites, make sure you reset the rewrite rules, instructions in commented code above.

I don't know how amazon expects the keywords, but they should be `urlencode()`'ed

Comment: That looks like a great solution, ( although would be nicer with /goto/amazon/42  )  but seems to fail when clicking the link.  Just gives a blank "Wordpress error" page.

Comment: sorry I did that off the top of my head. the error is from `wp_die();` it should be `exit`.

Comment: Ah yes thats working now, unfortunately however the keywords are not passing to the URL when it goes through to amazon.   Im using advanced custom fields plugin if that makes any difference ?

Comment: Maybe url_encode() them?

Comment: I've updated the post to include url rewrites, so you can get the `/goto/amazon/##/`

Comment: Thanks for going into more detail David its so appreciated.  We are getting there, it all acts how id like it,  apart from now when the link is clicked, it shows a white screen with the keywords on it,  rather than using those keywords in an amazon URL.

Comment: Been trying to figure this out myself but no luck,  it seems the "goto" line where its reading the keywords entered in the field is what it is showing,  rather than using the link

Comment: Any ideas David what the issue could be ?

Comment: yeah, use `get_field()` instead of `the_feild()` for `$keywds`.

Comment: Ahhh god I thought about that the other night and forgot about it by the time i got to my computer lol.  Thanks David that sorted it.  Will mark your answer as correct thank you very much.   Could I apply that same code to using wp_title instead of keywords ?  I'm going to run an if statement where if no keywords exist,  use the wp_title instead.

Comment: i guess. i dont know the context of your site. but note wp_title is a template tag, it echos instead of return by default, so pass the second param as `true` to make sure it returns a value to your var, ie: `wp_title(', ',true)`